# tooltip on dynamic created content in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

How to trigger the tooltip from a content has just created dynamically from jquery?

I use append function to append a `"p"` element into a content and with title attribute as well.

Every time I need to hover twice on the a newly created element then the `tooltip` box will appear. Otherwise hovering on the element first time will show nothing always.

This is my `tooltip` function. Or maybe I can get the class name and do the matching somehow. Please do guide me.

```
$(".tooltip_class").tooltip({
    show: null,
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom"
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + 10 }, "fast" );
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle showing the problem? or the code you're using for the tooltip?

Comment: currently my code is 

$(document).tooltip({
 show: null,
 position: {
  my: "left top",
  at: "left bottom"
 },
 open: function( event, ui ) {
  ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + 10 }, "fast" );
 }
 
});

Comment: I want to get the class name so i can match it to whether to show the tooltip or not. because i have other element which contain title as well but not all title must show inside a jquery tooltip

Comment: please update the code in your question, not everyone reads the comments..

Comment: @Michael You need to put the HTML code here, if you want others to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to put the content as title attribute value. Instead the content can be added in jQuery as follows:

**Javascript**

```
$( document ).tooltip();
$('#selector').tooltip( "option", "content", "TOOLTIP CONTENT" );
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="help">
 <a id="selector" title="">  
    What's this?
</a>
</span>
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DBHc9/1/)

Comment: does not work on dynamically added hyperlink. i want display dynamically added hyperlink title (with html table content) on hyperlink hover. do you know how to achieve