# jQuery tooltip not working on dynamically loaded HTML content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Site consists of 3 pages, index.html, 1.html, 2.html.
The goal is to load html from 1.html which contains tooltip and some other htmls and display it in a div, after mouseover on the loaded tooltips I want tooltip texts to be fetched from 2.html.
**However this code does not works, no error is shown and AJAX is never executed.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".content span" ).tooltip({
        track:true,
        open: function( event, ui ) {
              var id = this.id; 
              var userid = $(this).attr('data-id');
              
              $.ajax({
                  url:'2.html',
                  type:'post',
                  data:{userid:userid},
                  success: function(response){
                      $("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);
                  }
              });
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
}

.content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content span{
    width: 250px;
}

.content span:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamically show data in the Tooltip using AJAX</title>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" id="btnLoad" value="Load"/>
        <div class='container' id="container"></div>
    </body>
<script>
$( "#btnLoad" ).click(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "1.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $('#container').html(msg);
    $(this).tooltip();
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Sample HTML of 1.html file

```
            <div class='content'>
            <span title='Please wait..' data-id='1' id='user_1'>Pepsi</span>
        </div>

        <div class='content'>
            <span title='Please wait..' data-id='2' id='user_2'>7 Up</span>
        </div>
```

Sample HTML of 2.html file

```
This Tooltip text will be replaced with texts from Database
```

Comment: `$(".content span").tooltip({` only works on elements that exist at the time the code runs - so you need to run this after you add new elements.

Comment: @freedomn-m  Please guide how to do so

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440725/tooltip-on-dynamic-created-content-in-jquery) work for you? See [API doc](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/), it's about using event delegation.

Comment: After your code that "*JS scrips loads content from this PHP code*", add the same code that starts with `$(".content span").tooltip({`

Comment: @freedomn-m It does not work :(

Comment: @vee Sorry but that does not works for me

Comment: Your next step then is to provide a snippet that includes your initial tooltip setup and then some dynamically loaded html (after the initial tooltip setup).   See [mcve].  As it is, you've not shown when/how (the js) you load your "dynamically loaded html".   It's not clearly you actually have "dynamically *loaded* html" - ie HTML loaded via ajax after the page has loaded - but rather might be dynamically *generated* HTML - a snippet will show us what you're doing.

Comment: Though I may also be misreading your problem - your title is "dynamically loaded *html*" - but your question is "dynamically loaded *content*" where the content is html - so is the issue that your tooltip works, but not when the content of that tooltip is loaded dynamically?  (rather than not being applied to late-loaded html)

Comment: It would be useful to see the *rendered* html that you're applying the tooltip to, as well as a response from the tooltip ajax.

Comment: @freedomn-m Please check !

Comment: in simple -> A button on index.php loads content from news.php, and on this content I want tooltip, the tooltip should load content from info.php?id=

Comment: @freedomn-m I've tried to make the question cleaner, plz check

Comment: @vee I've used code snippets to make the question cleaner, plz check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UPDATED

Your updated question is considerably clearer, and helped me track down what is happening.  My original answer solved one of the issues, but not all.  There are actually a series of problems.

##### Problem 1

The first problem is the one I previously described: jQuery selectors only match page elements that exist *at page load*.  `$(".content span").tooltip()` will only initialise tooltips for `span`s that exist inside `.content` at page load.  If you inject new `span`s later (or new `.content`s with `span`s inside them), they are not included, and they won't have tooltips.

The simplest fix is to use the ([apparently undocumented](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)?) `selector` tooltip option.  Initialise the tooltips on an HTML element *which exists at page load*, and then use the `selector` option to filter to only match the elements you really want to have tooltips on.  The key is the filtering part happens live, and so will match newly added elements.

In your case, we can't use `.content` for the tooltip, since that does not exist at page load either.  We need some parent element which exists on the page before any of your AJAX stuff happens.  Let's assume you have a parent like `<div class="parent">`, and your HTML will be injected into that (I guess you could also use `body` or `document`).  So we initialise the tooltips on that parent div:

```
$(".parent").tooltip({
    // the selector option filters the elements that will actually have tooltips
    selector: '.content span'
});
```

##### Problem 2

Now we have basic tooltip functionality working, even for new content injected in to the page.  The next step is to dynamically load content over AJAX, and update the tooltip's title with that content.  Normally you would do that like this:

```
$(selector).tooltip('option', 'content', 'New tooltip text!');
```

where `selector` is something matching the individual `span` we're currently viewing the tooltip for.  But in our case, that won't work - that `span` **has no tooltip attached!**  Because we're initialising tooltips on `.parent`, the individual `span`s where the tooltips show up do not have a tooltip attached, and calling `.tooltip()` on them will fail with an error like:

> cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

To reference the existing tooltip, we need to do `$('.parent').tooltip()`, but if we do:

```
// Don't do this
$('.parent').tooltip('option', 'content', 'New tooltip text!');
```

It would change *every* tooltip on the page to the same `'New tooltip text!'`, and we don't want that.

The `.open` event handler you are using to fire your AJAX [receives the jQuery `event` as a parameter](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open).  And that `event` includes info about the currently targeted element.  Using that, we can find which span on the page we are really currently looking at:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
  // Find real targeted tooltip
  let target = $(event.originalEvent.target);
```

So now we can manipulate that element's title:

```
$target.attr('title', 'New tooltip!');
```

We can also make it a tooltip!

```
$target.tooltip();
```

In fact this is not enough, because the `.parent` tooltip is already open and showing "Please wait ...".  The above steps do update the title, but you have to move your mouse away and then back to see it.  We want the content to refresh immediately, live.  I tried some experimentation and found this works well:

```
// Temporarily disabling the parent tooltip hides the one that was already open
$('.parent').tooltip('disable');

// Update our target's title
$target.attr('title', 'New tooltip!');

// Initialise a tooltip on our target, and immediately open it
$target.tooltip().tooltip('open');

// Re-enable the parent tooltips, so this process will work again for other spans
$('.parent').tooltip('enable');
```

So we are actually adding new tooltip instances to the page, each time we mouse-over a matching span.  This approach has the added advantage that the new tooltip replaces the old, parent one for the specific `span`.  That means the parent tooltip options no longer apply to `span`s that have already had their tooltip content loaded, which means if you mouse-over it a 2nd time, it does not fire the AJAX request a 2nd time for that `span`.  The content we got from the first AJAX call is already there and simply re-used.

Here's a working snippet demonstrating all of this.

I've used https://www.npoint.io/ which is a JSON storage bin, to simulate your AJAX calls.  I have no affiliation with it, it just seems like a handy tool.  Unfortunately it does not seem very reliable, and requests to it failed a few times while I was working.  If that happens, pls retry.

I added a few bins with data matching your `1.html` and `2.html` files, the code below loads them and uses their content:

- [This bin](https://api.npoint.io/6893d2fd7632835742cf) includes your HTML content;
- [This bin](https://api.npoint.io/06cf752b395286e41cb4) includes dummy data for user ID 0;
- [This bin](https://api.npoint.io/2a3e0a338f92a803b3fc) includes dummy data for user ID 1;
- [This bin](https://api.npoint.io/a9a4296244c36e8d5bfc) includes dummy data for user ID 2;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // This URL returns a JSON response including HTML like your 1.html,
    // this way we can realistically simulate your 1.html AJAX call.
    let htmlContentUrl = 'https://api.npoint.io/6893d2fd7632835742cf';

    // These URLs return JSON responses including plain text like your
    // 2.html file, this way we can realistically simulate AJAX calls 
    // loading and using data from your DB
    let userContentUrls = [
        'https://api.npoint.io/06cf752b395286e41cb4',
        'https://api.npoint.io/2a3e0a338f92a803b3fc',
        'https://api.npoint.io/a9a4296244c36e8d5bfc'
    ];

    // We use this selector a few times, it is good practice to cache it
    var $parent = $('.parent');

    $("#btnLoad").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: htmlContentUrl,
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $('#container').html(msg.content);
        });
    });

    $parent.tooltip({
        selector: '.conten span',
        track: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            // Find real targetted tooltip
            var $target = $(event.originalEvent.target);
            var userid = $target.attr('data-id');
            url = userContentUrls[userid];
            console.log('For userid', userid, 'url is', url);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    userid: userid
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    // We can't simply update the tooltip for $target, because
                    // it *has* no tooltip!  The tooltip is actually attached
                    // to .parent.  To refresh the already visible tooltip, we
                    // need to take a few steps.
                    $parent.tooltip('disable');
                    $target.attr('title', response.content);
                    $target.tooltip().tooltip('open');
                    $parent.tooltip('enable');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content span {
  width: 250px;
}

.content span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <span id="user_0" title="Please wait ..." data-id="0">Water</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="button" id="btnLoad" value="Load" />

  <div class='container' id="container"></div>

</div>
```

##### Side notes:

- I added a tooltip (user ID 0) which is visible on page load, just to demonstrate everything is working both on page load and after new content is injected;
- [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) is to use GET when retrieving data, and POST for changing data.  Your AJAX calls are just retrieving data to display, so really should be GET;
- I wasn't sure why you had `context: document.body`, but I don't think it is necessary, and to keep things simple I removed it;
- If you are going to use a jQuery selector more than once, [it makes sense to cache them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291841/does-jquery-do-any-kind-of-caching-of-selectors).  I did that for `$parent`, and `$target`.

Comment: Thnx for your great reply, but sorry it did not helped. My question was "A button on index.php loads content from modal.php, and on this content I want tooltip, the tooltip should load content from tooltip.php?pid=" Your ans does not load anything from the 3rd page.

Comment: Because that is not relevant to the problem you have ... The tooltips don't work, because they are injected dynamically.  Whether you load tooltip content via AJAX or not is not relevant to the problem.  Once you get tooltips working, they will load your content via AJAX. Did you try either fix I described?

Comment: I tried that, but it justs shows "Loading..." , the AJAX is not fired

Comment: What is the purpose of the `.mouseout()` code? It will remove the tooltip you just loaded, so it has to be re-loaded again later.  I guess the tooltip contents can change, so must always be fresh?

Comment: Tooltip contents doest not change.

Comment: I'll try again - What is the purpose of the `.mouseout()` code?

Comment: to hide the tooltip

Comment: I'm confused.  Tooltips are hidden when you mouseout by default, you don't need to add code to do that ... I mean that's what a tooltip *is*, something that is shown on mouseover, and hidden on mouseout. You can see this in my example ... Is that really the only reason you have that code?  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Removing that block of code does nothing.

Comment: I've made the question cleaner by using code snippets, give it a chance.

Comment: thnx a ton buddy !

Comment: Why this does not work for mobile ? It keep showing "Please wait ..." @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to push this line to your code.

```
$('body').tooltip({selector: '.content span'});
```

Right after

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // push the above line here
    ... your current code

}
```

Comment: The problem is more than just selector, I want some ajax action on this too, unfortunately which does not get fired :(

Comment: this is because of the New DOM is not binding the function tooltip.
So can you try to push $('body').tooltip({selector: '.content span'}); at the line after the Ajax call done?